# Error on second datagrid..multiple initializers for dataprovider

Tags: apache-flex

I have a main datagrid, and want to launch a window with another datagrid in it, bringing in a different dataprovider.  However, when I do this it acts funnny, brings in some default datagrid information and then gives me an error when I try to set the dataprovider:

"multiple initializers for property dataprovider. (note: 'dataprovider' is the default property of mx.controls.datagrid)"

ANyone know what this means, or what I could be doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

doh.. was just missing the  wrapper on my datagrid.  Weird error though, wish it would have just said "your missing ...".

Comment: Thanks for the info, I was stuck with the same problem until I came across this and realized that I was missing the <mx:columns> tag around my <mx:DataGridColumn> tags. Doh!

Comment: I got this error from having my gridlines accidentally outside of my backgroundElements in a PlotChart.  worst error decription ever? lol